# Unable to scroll through the activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following activity where I have an imageview , 2 flipper views and a gridview along with a navigation drawer.As gridView is a scroll enabled activity by default ,earlier only my gridview was scrollable. I wanted my whole activity to be scrollable instead of just the gridView , so for that I put my frameLayout inside a nestedScrollView.
I also set grid.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) in my MainActivity.java .

Here's my xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehaviour">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffff"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.xxx.xxx.MainActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="61dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/banner1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


            <technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout
                android:id="@+id/flipper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b1" />

            <technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout
                android:id="@+id/Flipper2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="67dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flipper">

            </technolifestyle.com.imageslider.FlipperLayout>

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="542dp"
                android:background="#ffff"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Flipper2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.615" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:background="#ffff"
        app:itemTextColor="#0f0f0f"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black_overlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Change the heights of your `FrameLayout` and `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content`

Comment: still doesn't work only scrollable for like 5dp height